Why does POST not change the source code in my project? Using Visual Studio to edit, and ASP.NET Core Web API
Why does POST not change the source code in my project? Using Visual Studio to edit, and ASP.NET Core Web API.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CountryAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AppController : ControllerBase
    {
        private List<string> weekDay = new List<string>()
        {
            "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
        };

        // GET: api/App
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return weekDay;
        }

        // POST api/App
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return BadRequest("Value cannot be null or empty.");
            }

            weekDay.Add(value);
            return Ok(); // Return 200 OK if successful
        }
    }
}

Expected list to modify with POST, but GET does not show change to list

What you have is a fundamental misunderstanding of how code works.  (Which puts this pretty close to a "typo" for closing the question.)  It's not going to change the source code.  If you want to persist data across multiple requests, you need to save that data somewhere.  A database is a common example.  Other examples include saving data to a file, or even just storing the data in session if you only need it temporarily as a proof of concept between two consecutive requests.

Each time a request is made to the controller, a new instance of the controller is created. Therefore, the weekDay list is re-initialized with its default values for each request, and any changes made during a POST request are not persisted across different requests.
To persist changes across requests, there are many ways you could achieve. By reading your code logic, I suggest you use a service with a longer lifespan than the controller. You can use dependency injection to achieve this by registering a service with a scope that persists across multiple requests (e.g., singleton or scoped).
1.Create an interface
public interface IWeekDayService
{
    List<string> GetWeekDays();
    void AddWeekDay(string value);
}

2.Implement the service
public class WeekDayService : IWeekDayService
{
    private List<string> weekDay = new List<string>()
    {
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
    };

    public List<string> GetWeekDays()
    {
        return weekDay;
    }

    public void AddWeekDay(string value)
    {
        weekDay.Add(value);
    }
}

3.Inject the service
public class AppController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IWeekDayService _weekDayService;

    public AppController (IWeekDayService weekDayService)
    {
        _weekDayService = weekDayService;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return _weekDayService.GetWeekDays();
    }

    // POST api/App
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return BadRequest("Value cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        _weekDayService.AddWeekDay(value);
        return Ok(); // Return 200 OK if successful
    }
}

4.Register the service
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWeekDayService, WeekDayService>(); // Singleton service

